# Apache POI for excel get dependent cells

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am writing a program that reads excel files using apache POI. I'm getting all the values, but I want to know which cells are dependent on others (using the formula for the cell). 
I've tried using `String formula = cell.getCellFormula()`, but this just returns me the cell index (eg. H5). Is there any other way I can do this?
Here's my code for reading cells:

```
private void handleCell(int type,Cell cell) 
{

    switch (type) 
    {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            String form = cell.getCellFormula();
            handleCell(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType(),cell);
            break;
        default :

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser`.
It has a static method

```
public static Ptg[] parse(
    java.lang.String formula,
    FormulaParsingWorkbook workbook,
    int formulaType,
    int sheetIndex)
```

according to the documentation, it parses a formula string into a List of tokens in RPN order.

The tokens (Ptg = "parse things") can be checked for their type (REF/VALUE/ARRAY) using `public final byte getPtgClass()`.

I have not tested it, but it may be the way to go. Parse the formula, then check each Ptg entry for the type (REF?) and get the destination cell.

See:

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/FormulaParser.html
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ptg/Ptg.html

Comment: You'll want the `Ref*` and `Area*` ptgs to get the references of cells they apply to, but basically that's your best way, yes!

Comment: Thanks Udo and Gagravarr! I was finally able to do it using the FormulaParser class. Here's how I got the cell index : `byte cla = ptg[i].getPtgClass();
           if(cla == Ptg.CLASS_VALUE)
           {
            System.out.println (ptg[i].toFormulaString());
           }`

Comment: They are marked as Internal...And they even go as far as to reiterate it: "For POI internal use only".